# What to do if ActiveMQ Artemis does not deliver messages which have not been processed?

Tags: java, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

I have a transaction manager set up for consumer.

```java
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(
        @Qualifier("jmsSimpleConnectionFactory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer containerFactoryConfigurer,
        PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {

    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory listenerContainerFactory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();

    containerFactoryConfigurer.configure(listenerContainerFactory, connectionFactory);

    listenerContainerFactory.setMessageConverter(this.jmsMessageConverter);
    listenerContainerFactory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
    listenerContainerFactory.setCacheLevel(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.CACHE_CONNECTION);
    listenerContainerFactory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);

...
```

```java
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return new JmsTransactionManager(connectionFactory);
}
```

Also, the ability is configured from the service to automatically pick up messages from the DLL and send them back to the queue so that the service can re-process them.

```java
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory dlqListenerContainerFactory(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(jmsSimpleConnectionFactory);
    factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
    factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
    return factory;
}
```

```java
@JmsListener(destination = "DLQ", containerFactory = "dlqListenerContainerFactory")
public void processDLQMessage(String message) {
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(sourceQueue, message);
}
```

However, this approach works. When an exception appears in the consumer's transactional method (the method is marked with the `@Transactional` annotation) and the transaction is considered unsuccessful, only then the message being processed will be placed in the DLQ.

But if at the time of processing the message the consumer service turns off then such a message will simply disappear from the queue. However, I would like it to be delivered processed to the queue.

What else can be configured? Share your knowledge.

Comment: If you are using a transacted JMS session and your consumer closes (for whatever reason) before you acknowledge the message and commit the transaction then the message will be put back onto the original queue. It shouldn't simply "disappear from the queue."

Comment: As I said above, if an error occurs, the message that could not be processed is placed in the DLQ. However, if just at the moment of executing the transactional method, the service-consumerit will be turned off suddenly, then the message is not returned to the queue. Why does Artemis think that the message has been processed? It was checked on Artemis deployed in Docker.